# symfony and mathjax compatibility

Tags: symfony, twig, character, mathjax

after many search on google, it seems that my problem is not very well documented.

I am developping a symfony blog which contains maths. So I have tried to use mathjax. It works well but the problem is that the character '&' and '\\' are not send as it is in the web page (when I look in the source code of the firefox, the character are : '& amp;' and '& #92;').

The content is stored in the database and the characters in the database are correct.
Is there clean way to solve the problem ? Maybe by Mathjax side or Symfony side ?

I have tried to use raw twig filter but the character are still the same in the source code.

Thank you very much :)

**EDIT:**
I use **knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle** with the default filter to print the post content : `post.content|markdown`, and when I retire the `|markdown` the characters are correct but I have not the markdown conversion...

**EDIT 2:** Ok after a morning of search, I found what is my problem. Me, I parse the markdown into back end (php) and then javascript  parse the html (markdown -> mathjax). But usually, all is done with javascript in this sense : mathjax -> markdown. like in this app : https://github.com/kerzol/markdown-mathjax.

So my new question is, is there a way to make mathjax reverse the markdown parser ?

Comment: You can try disabling autoescape: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html. If you still have difficulties then updated your question with some sample twig.

Comment: Can you give any more information? How is it stored? How are you retrieving the content? There's nothing special about Symfony that will prevent you from doing what you are wanting.

Comment: @Cerad "Characters in the database are correct"and it is printed like that : ``post.content|markdown``. This morning, I tried to remove the markdown filter, and it reveals me that it was this filter which transform characters. I use **knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle** with the default filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a answer on my own but it is not very elegant. What I want is to unparse the text between $ $ and $$ $$. So I've done that :

```
$html = $this->container->get('markdown.parser')
    ->transformMarkdown($post->getContent());
$html = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $html);
$html = str_replace('&#92;', '\\\\', $html);
$html = str_replace('<em>', '_', $html);
$html = str_replace('</em>', '_', $html);

$post->setContent($html);
```

and in the view :

```
{{ post.content|raw }}
```

It is working but this is not beautifull at all.